# Payable addresses in smart contracts

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm learning solidity by looking at smart contracts and I see the following code:

```
        function withdraw(uint256 amount, address recipient) public onlyOwner {
        require(
            amount <= address(this).balance,
            "Requested amount exceeds the contract balance."
        );
        require(
            recipient != address(0),
            "Recipient address cannot be the zero address."
        );
        payable(recipient).transfer(amount);
    }

    function transfer(uint256 amount, address to) public {
        amount = (amount == 0) ? balances[msg.sender] : amount;
        require(
            amount > 0 && balances[msg.sender] >= amount,
            "It's not enough money on balance"
        );
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - amount;
        payable(to).transfer(amount);
    }
```

What's the difference between the two payable(...).transfer calls?

By the names I would assume that withdraw would transfer from the contract to the address and transfer would do the opposite, but I don't understand why that would be the case since the transfer calls are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The function `withdraw`:

```
function withdraw(uint256 amount, address recipient) public onlyOwner {
    require(
        amount <= address(this).balance,
        "Requested amount exceeds the contract balance."
    );
    require(
        recipient != address(0),
        "Recipient address cannot be the zero address."
    );
    payable(recipient).transfer(amount);
}
```

Can be called only by the authorized owner, if `onlyOwner` implemented as the name says.
It takes an `amount` and a `recipient`, first it checks if the amount is less than the current balance of the address then if the recipient isn't the zero address.
In the end, as from the Solidity docs: ".transfer(uint256 amount): send given amount of Wei to Address, throws on failure", it will transfer the `amount` in Wei to the `recipient` address.

While the function `transfer`:

```
function transfer(uint256 amount, address to) public {
    amount = (amount == 0) ? balances[msg.sender] : amount;
    require(
        amount > 0 && balances[msg.sender] >= amount,
        "It's not enough money on balance"
    );
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - amount;
    payable(to).transfer(amount);
}
```

Can be called only by anyone.
It takes an `amount` and an address `to`, first it takes the amount specified in the call or the entire msg.sender (caller) balance if the amount is zero. Then it checks if the amount is greater than zero and if the balance of the caller is higher or equal than the amount.
In the end it deducts the amount from the caller balance and, as from the Solidity docs: ".transfer(uint256 amount): it sends given amount of Wei to Address, throws on failure", it will transfer the `amount` in Wei to the `to` address.

Note, balance is not the amount of Wei an user has, since from the docs: ".balance (uint256): balance of the Address in Wei". It might be a mapping from address to int indicating the contract's balance of a user.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but what I still don't understand is if both functions take amount from the adresses sent as params or is there any difference I'm not seeing?

Comment: Yes, the caller has to specify both the amount to be sent and the address to send the amount. In the first case it checks if the amount is valid and sends funds from the contract, in the second case it checks if the amount is valid and sends funds from the caller from its contract balance.

Answer (score 0):

**Withdraw** function:

- This function is used here to withdraw funds from the smart contract and it will only be called by the owner. Also, it takes two arguments:

  1. **amount**: This is the amount the owner wants to withdraw from the smart contract and it should be less than or equal to the balance of the smart contract.
  2. **recipient**: This is the account address to which the owner wants to send the amount.

**Note**: The amount in this function will be deducted from the smart contract and added to the recipient's address.

**Transfer** function:

- This function is also used to withdraw funds from the smart contract but it is callable by anyone. Also, it takes two arguments:

  1. **amount**: This is the amount msg.sender wants to withdraw from the smart contract and it should be less than or equal to the balance of the msg.sender available in the contract which is tracked by using the mapping data structure.
  2. **to**: This is the account address to which the msg.sender wants to send the amount.

**Note**: The amount in this function will also be deducted from the smart contract and added to the **"to"** address.

So both of the functions here are doing the same thing which is withdrawing fund to some account address. The only difference is that **withdraw** can only be called by the owner and **transfer** can be called by  anyone who wants to transfer their fund from smart contract to some other address.